# if statement that evaluates to true gets skipped by control flow / interpreter

Tags: python-3.x

I´m currently working on bisectional-search to find the square root of any pos or neg integer. The below examples tries to find the square root of x -25 but my program enters an infinite loop because it skips an IF statement that evaluates to true and instead continues with else,
hence my search area does not get defined correctly.

I checked the control flow with pythontutor and saw that the interpreter skips a IF statement:

At this point guess = -12.5 and i want to check if -12.5**2 < ,
which evaluates to -156,25 < -25 and is true.

```
    In: -12.5**2 < -25
    Out: True
```

checked in the shell and it return correctly TRUE, yet when i execute the code it will skip this statement and continue with else:

```
    x = -25
    epsilon = 0.01
    numGuesses = 0
    low = 0.0
    high = x
    guess = (high+low)/2.0

    while abs(guess**2 - x) >= epsilon:
        if x > 0:
            print('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'guess =', guess)
            numGuesses += 1
        if guess**2 < x:
            low = guess
        else:
            high = guess
        guess = (high+low)/2.0
        elif x < 0:
            low = x
            high = 0.0
            print('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'guess =', guess)
            numGuesses += 1
        if guess**2 < x:
            low = guess
        else:
            high = guess
        guess = (high+low)/2.0
    print('numGuesses = ', numGuesses)
    print(guess, 'is close to the square root of', x)
```

Comment: `(-12.5)**2` = `+156.25` which is > `-25`. Then it will obviously evaluated to False. When you are using python shell to verify, you must have done `-12.5**2 < -25`. Here   12.5 is squared first and then `-` is applied which may be lead to your confusion.

Comment: Thanky you very much for taking the time to answer this.